# Module 'Swift' has no member named 'Task'

Tags: swift

I have created an enum named `Task` in my project. Now I want to use the Swift `Task` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task).

When I want to use Swift `Task` I wrote:
`Swift.Task { ... }` but I get the error: `Module 'Swift' has no member named 'Task'`

Comment: Which version of Swift (in which version of Xcode) are you compiling your code with?

Comment: Swift 5 in Xcode 13.3

Comment: If you `import _Concurrency` and replace `Swift.Task` with `_Concurrency.Task`, does that change the output?

Comment: Yes it does, works now!

Comment: Better solution: Don't do that. Rename _your_ type to avoid clash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to support [backdeployment of Swift concurrency features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746388/swift-concurrency-announced-for-ios-13-in-xcode-13-2-how-did-they-achieve-this/69747005#69747005) to older operating systems, Swift builds the concurrency APIs [into a separate library](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/a7edd6065c5abd5de0903b3fd4e12a92e13ea807/stdlib/public/Concurrency) which can be shipped separately from the Swift standard library. This [`swift_Concurrency` library](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a7edd6065c5abd5de0903b3fd4e12a92e13ea807/stdlib/public/Concurrency/CMakeLists.txt#L72) is exposed as an implicit module called `_Concurrency`, which is re-exported from the Swift standard library.

However, the Swift concurrency classes and types still belong to this implementation-only library, so in order to disambiguate, you'll need to write `_Concurrency.Task` instead of `Swift.Task`.

You can also see this in Xcode: if you refer to `Task` in a new project, and ^-⌘-click on the symbol to jump to its definition, you'll find it in the `_Concurrency` library interface:

[image: Task interface definition in Xcode]

---

Instead of explicitly writing out `_Concurrency.Task` in order to disambiguate everywhere, consider the following:

1. You can create a `typealias` for the type (e.g. `typealias SwiftTask = _Concurrency.Task`) if you prefer your own `Task` type taking precedence, and don't want to rename it
2. Alternatively, depending on whether it makes sense for your project (and is reasonable in context): this might be an opportunity to consider a more specific name for your type to possibly avoid both nominal and logical conflicts. `async`/`await` and `Task` are major new language/stdlib features that are going to be influential for a long time, so it *may* make sense to pick a less general word if the stdlib is going to be reserving that one going forward

Comment: Good info, upvoted, but I can't agree with your recommendation. It was not very respectful or prudent to name the type `Task`, when so many other apps need `Task` types—especially when those `Task`s probably represent the word better than Swift does, where the meaning is not obvious until you read documentation about it.

Comment: @Jessy I don't disagree that naming conflicts are unfortunate, though I think passing judgement on the naming of the stdlib type is outside of scope for me here... I tried rephrasing in an even more neutral way, since it's really up to OP what `Task` better represents for them.